# Geoprocessing buffer "." files are not supported for this algorithm

Tags: qgis, vector, buffer, geoprocessing, error

I am trying to buffer a layer which worked earlier. I recieve, `The "." files are not supported for this algorithm`

Other tools give me the same error along with `Fix Geometries, Reproject Layer...`

My buffer layer disappeared while reloading the map file I saved. I tried restarting my PC to see if the software was to blame. I suspect my installation might be corrupted unless there is some other reason this would occur. Should I reinstall QGIS?

I am using v. 3.16 most stable

I am trying to convert DMS data with a bad degrees sign, it has geometry errors, so I might assume that Fix Geometries should allow me to render a CSV file into a vector points after.

Please see the CSV file
[Link click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b-XyuVrw5XlQXVRUZ82yY4u9clFOiqhF/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

I just added the file's code I wanted the output to come out as (in my case .kml) after the name I had assigned for the output, and it worked. Turns out I just needed to manually add it.